# How many separate streams/mount-points does icecast support?

Tags: linux, streaming, audio-streaming, icecast

Does anyone know how many separate streams/mount-points icecast supports? I wasn't able to find an answer on Mr. Google or the icecast docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like icecast has no stream restrictions and therefore the only things limiting the possible amount of concurrent streams are the OS, the [hardware](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.0.1/config-file.html) you use and icecast's configuration as stated [here](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.0.1/config-file.html).

Excerpt from [here](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/icecast/2005-October/009994.html) and [here](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/icecast/2005-October/009993.html):

Question:

> Is there a theoretical maximum to the number of mountpoints icecast
>   can handle?

Answer:

> As for limits: yes, but it'll be highly platform specific, and is not
>   a limit in icecast itself. You'll probably first hit either a limit on
>   the number of threads permitted (one per source, plus a few for the
>   rest of icecast), or the limit on open file descriptors (one per
>   source, plus one per client, plus a few for the rest of icecast)